# com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message length is less than the maximum message length 4194304

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to get the documents in a mongodb collection using a databricks script in pyspark. I am trying to fetch the data for each day.
Script works fine for some days but sometime it throws following error for some day.

```
com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message length 14484499 is less than the maximum message length 4194304.
```

Not sure what this error is and how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated.

This is the sample code I am running:

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{'$and':[{'UpdatedTimestamp':{'$gte': 1555891200000}},
                               {'UpdatedTimestamp':{'$lt': 1555977600000}}]}}]

READ_MSG = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
               .option("uri",connectionstring)
               .option("pipeline",pipeline)
               .load()
```

The datetime is provided in epoch format.

Answer (score 2):

It is more a comment than an answer (I have not enough reputation to post comments).

I have the same issue.
After some Research I found out that it was my nested field "survey" with more than 1 sublevel that was creating the issue, since I was able to read the db by selecting all the other fields except this one:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _t: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- streetAddress1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- survey: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- SurveyQuestionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Is there anyone getting closer to a workaround to what seems to be a bug of the mongodb spark connector?

Answer (score 0):

After adding appName in the mongo db connection string, the issue seems to be resolved. I am not getting this error now.